# xcode problems installing, apple keeps telling me to upgrade?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

Ive just spent the best part of 3 hours updating my mac (because apple told me xcode 6 wont run unless I install 10.7.4). However, now Ive done that, apple now tells me xcode 6 wont run unless I install 10.10? Is that right? A whole new OS with no path to upgrade?

Im wondering can I use older versions of xcode? Where can I download these? Will I still be able to submit to the app store with older versions of xcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's right, if you want to install the latest version of Xcode you will need OSX 10.10 or later (see "Compatibility" section [here](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12)).

If you use an older version you will not be able to support newer versions of iOS/OSX.

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to install the latest Xcode 6.3.x (iOS 8.3 SDK) you need OSX Yosemite installed.

There is a grace period of a few weeks during which you can still release with the previous version of the SDK, but not older than that. You should still have a few weeks of Xcode 6.2 left...